# Display Page in pop up using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button on my web page. once I click on the button a pop-up will appear with some text. here I need to display another HTML page in that pop-up 
I have given my code below please help me

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="popModal.css">
</head>
<body>
<button id="notifyModal_ex1" class="btn btn-primary">Example</button>
<div id="content2" style="display:none">
    ghjgh
</div>
<script src="popModal.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#notifyModal_ex1').click(function(){
            $('#content2').notifyModal({
                duration : 1500,
                placement : 'center',
                overlay : true,
                type : 'notify',

                onClose : function() {}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you press `f12` to open the developer console then go to the `console` tab and let us know what it says there. There will be probably an error which will give us more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#content2').load("page/url").notifyModal()
```

To show a loading message:

```
$('#content2').text("Loading, please wait...").load("page/url").notifyModal()
```

Or to open the modal when load ends:

```
$('#content2').load("page/url", function() {
    $('#content2').notifyModal();
})
```

As described in [`load() docs`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

So it will load an html response and *append* it to the target element.

Comment: $('#content2').load("index.html").notifyModal({.., Still this not working

Comment: @KannanChakkara it should because `load()` supports directly .html files. Try this test: Remove `display:none` from `content2` element, then this `$('#content2').load("index.html")` and tell us the results. Check if the content is load into the div.

Comment: No still not working..  $('#content2').load("index.html")({

Comment: @KannanChakkara ok. You'll have to provide more details about this request. Can you check your "Network" tab in your browser? A simple `load()` should work in any *visible*  `div`.